# Make function not global in script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have only ONE function inside script tag in my HTML and will be used for event click. Is it possible to make this function not in global scope?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(sender, args) {
}
</script>
```

Comment: How you are going to use it for event click ?

Comment: You can wrap all the code in the tag within an IIFE, that way you can avoid all the globals. But if you're doing that, you've to use `addEventListener` to attach events to the elements on the page, inline listeners can find global functions only.

Comment: Note: if you're using `onclick=` in your HTML, it won't be able to find functions that are not global.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), and register event handlers in that only, something like this

```
(function () {
  function myFunction(sender, args) {}

  $(".your_button").on("click", function () {
    myFunction();
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to IIFE, as you've tagged this [jquery], you can wrap it all in doc.ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    function myFunction(sender, args) {
    }

    // example use:
    $(".button").click(function() { myFunction(this); });

  });
</script>
```

`myFunction` will only be available to code within the `{ }` of the doc.ready.

---

Note: if you're using `onclick=` in your HTML, it won't be able to find functions that are not global.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use `let` as the type of class, combined with a lambda(arrow) expression?

```js
let myFunction = (sender, args) => {
}
```

Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let